# Two tables on the same JTable

Tags: java, swing

I am new to this site if I make mistakes on the job thank you to tell me your valuable comment.
So the problem is that the display is bad on the JTable. I have a question table and a response I want to show the same JTable ( ManyToOne relation) But the answers are displayed ( With Bindings ) but the manner is false I do not want to see the ID and the answers to a question I want to see line by line.

```
JButton btnAfficher = new JButton("Afficher");
    btnAfficher.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            categorie=GestionCategorieDelegate.doFindCategorieById(PreparerTest.idCategorie);
            System.out.println(categorie);
            btnAfficher.setEnabled(false);
            if(Facile.getText().length()!=0)
            {
                questions.addAll(GestionTestDelegate.doPrepareRandomTest(Integer.parseInt(Facile.getText()), categorie,"Facile"));

            } 
            else
            {

            }
            if(Moyen.getText().length()!=0)
            {

                questions.addAll(GestionTestDelegate.doPrepareRandomTest(Integer.parseInt(Moyen.getText()), categorie, "Moyen"));

            }
            else
            {

            }
            if(Difficile.getText().length()!=0)
            {
                questions.addAll(GestionTestDelegate.doPrepareRandomTest(Integer.parseInt(Difficile.getText()), categorie, "Difficile"));

            }
            System.out.println(questions);
            initDataBindings();
        }
    }); 
    protected void initDataBindings() {
    JTableBinding<Question, List<Question>, JTable> jTableBinding = SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ, questions, table);
    //
    BeanProperty<Question, String> questionBeanProperty = BeanProperty.create("contenu");
    jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(questionBeanProperty).setColumnName("Contenu");
    //
    BeanProperty<Question, Collection<Reponse>> questionBeanProperty_1 = BeanProperty.create("reponses");
    jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(questionBeanProperty_1).setColumnName("Reponses");
    //
    jTableBinding.bind();
}
```

the result

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQvmB.png]

Comment: My first advise: use punctuation.

Comment: @pzaenger done thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. But maybe you can use a `JTree`. It will display a node with multiple child nodes. Check out the section fro the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html).

Comment: @camickr thank you for you're suggestion but i want to use a JTable i want to display one the same moment the question and in front of it their responses to be clear for the user i can not choose the attribuate to display for the table response?